# Trying to add a restart keystroke to my problem but facing encounters

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, pygame, restart

So I was trying to build this game using a free course on Youtube by Freecodeacademy(feel free to check them out) and after I finished I tried to add my own restart key log to the game. In the sense that I wanted that if people press R the game restarts.

I have tried the following methods

1. Put the game loop in a separate function and try to use recursion to replay the function over and over again but while the game does work, the images such as the bullet image or background does not load and hence it does not work properly
2. I have also tried creating a new python file in the same project and tried to import the main file over and over again using importlib.reload(main) but I can't seem to do that either.

I was wondering what else could the solution be and if there is a more efficient solution. I will leave my code down below and would appreciate any help.

Ps: I am only a armature in coding right now so I understand this problem might be small and stupid but I do want to learn from my failures and mistakes. Also I apologize if there is something wrong with anything in my question. This is my first question on stack overflow.

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer

pygame.init()  # This is to Initialise the game
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))  # create screen and set height

# Background
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')

# Background sound
mixer.music.load("background.wav")
mixer.music.play(-1)

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load("space-invaders.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0


def player(x, y):  # This function is used to display the value on the screen
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))  # Blit is used to display stuff on the screen


# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load("invader.png"))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(40)


def enemy(x, y, i):  # This function is used to display the value on the screen
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))  # Blit is used to display stuff on the screen


# Bullet
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"  # Ready state means bullet has not yet been fired, we use this as a bool

# Score
score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)
textX = 10
textY = 10

# Game Over Text
over_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 64)


def show_score(x, y):
    over_text = font.render("Score: " + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (x, y))


def game_over_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER ", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (200, 250))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # Background color
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Background image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():  # pygame.event.get() function is used to create a container of every action done
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Close game when cross is clicked
            running = False

        # Recording Keystrokes
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # KEYDOWN is used to check if key is pressed
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change += 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:  # Bullet Shot
                if bullet_state == "ready":
                    bullet_sound = mixer.Sound("laser.wav")
                    bullet_sound.play()
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, playerY)
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                restart = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:  # KEYUP is used to know if the key is released
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # Player Call
    playerX += playerX_change

    # Setting Boundaries
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        # Game Over
        if enemyY[i] > 440:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            break

        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -4
            enemyY += enemyY_change

        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            explosion_sound = mixer.Sound("explosion.wav")
            explosion_sound.play()
            bulletY = 480
            score_value += 1
            bullet_state = "ready"
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    # Bullet Movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state == "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, textY)

    # Constantly updates the changes
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that will reset any variables that change when the game is running:

```py
enemy_image = pygame.image.load("invader.png")

def resetGame():
    global playerX, playerY, playerX_change
    global enemyImg, enemyX, enemyY, enemyX_change, enemyY_change
    global score_value
    global bulletX, bulletY, bulletX_change, bulletY_change, bullet_state

    playerX = 370
    playerY = 480
    playerX_change = 0

    enemyImg = []
    enemyX = []
    enemyY = []
    enemyX_change = []
    enemyY_change = []
    num_of_enemies = 6
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyImg.append(enemy_image)
        enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
        enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
        enemyX_change.append(4)
        enemyY_change.append(40)

    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = 480
    bulletX_change = 0
    bulletY_change = 10
    bullet_state = "ready" 

    score_value = 0
```

Call the function once if the game needs to be restarted. You can even call the function   before the application loop instead of setting all the variables.